# Tkinter buttons run another program

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have four different python programs which I want to be executed as an event when the user presses a defined Tkinter button present on a separate python file. This python file looks like this so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def arvuta():

    return 

VCalc = Tk()
VCalc.title("V-Calc")
VCalc.configure(background='#E6F3FE')

nupp = ttk.Button(VCalc, text="prog1", command=arvuta)
nupp.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=3, pady=3, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

nupp2 = ttk.Button(VCalc, text="prog2", command=arvuta)
nupp2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=3, pady=3, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

nupp3 = ttk.Button(VCalc, text="prog3", command=arvuta)
nupp3.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=3, pady=3, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

nupp4 = ttk.Button(VCalc, text="prog4", command=arvuta)
nupp4.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=3, pady=3, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

VCalc.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to execute a python program from another one using Tkinter buttons?

Comment: if you want to execute another process, its best to use the `subprocess` module. It seems like its not quite the right thing to do. It will leave you with the prospect of using tedious and slow IPC techniques to communicate between the processes. Perhaps a good approach might be to use your other code as modules in this code. So you would import the existing module and call functions from it directly. I don't know if that is possible in your code.

Comment: I found one solution ,this is os system. " def arvuta():
    os.system('myprogram.py')"  Is it ok solution?

Comment: If it works for you it's ok. subprocess is more full featured that os.system it's worth learning if you do this kind of thing often.

Answer (score 1):

Use subprocesses

```
import subprocess
import sys

pid1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "file.py"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `execfile` python builtin. In the button definition, use: `command=lambda: execfile("path/to/file.py")`. If you want to keep your main window responsive, you might want to use multithreading.

Comment: Actually I tried different solutions. Finally i found "runpy ".  import runpy and runpy.run_path("mycode.py"). It works pretty good